# Create a new string from prefix up to character position in C++

Tags: c++, string

How can I find the position of a character in a string? Ex. If I input "abc*ab" I would like to create a new string with just "abc". Can you help me with my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::find` returns an iterator to the first element it finds that compares equal to what you're looking for (or the second argument if it doesn't find anything, in this case the end iterator.) You can construct a `std::string` using iterators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "abc*ab";
    std::string s2(s.begin(), std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), '*'));
    std::cout << s2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

C++ standard string provides a `find` method:

```
s.find(c)
```

returns the position of first instance of character `c` into string `s` or `std::string::npos` in case the character is not present at all. You can also pass the starting index for the search; i.e.

```
s.find(c, x0)
```

will return the first index of character `c` but starting the search from position `x0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `std::string` type, then it is very easy to find the position of a character, by using `std::find` algorithm like so:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string first_string = "abc*ab";
    string truncated_string = string( first_string.cbegin(), find( first_string.cbegin(), first_string.cend(), '*' ) );

    cout << truncated_string << endl;
}
```

**Note:** if your character is found multiple times in your `std::string`,  then the `find` algorithm will return the position of the occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on existing answers, you can use `string.find()` and `string.substr()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s = "abc*ab";
    size_t index = s.find("*");

    if (index != std::string::npos) {
        std::string prefix = s.substr(0, index);
        std::cout << prefix << "\n"; // => abc
    }
}
```